# Not able to click on button in android native app using appium 1.6.4

Tags: java, selenium, appium, react-native

I am not able to click on "logout" button. I used all possible approaches like 
locators, UISelector and tab using TouchAction class but it did not work out. Even getlocation().getX() method also not working to click the element, it's not throwing any exception.

[ImageOfElment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDkoa.png)

Comment: It would be helpful to post the markup involved and the locators you've tried.

Comment: Can you post your code how you approaches to click?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("LOGOUT")).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  // Update your xpath accordingly and use following code  
  @FindBy(xpath="//android.widget.buttonView[@text='logout']")
  private WebElement logoutbutton;

  if(logoutbutton.isEnabled())
  {
   logoutbutton.click();
  }


  // If your app is having id for this element then use following , update logout with id available in your app
  @FindBy(id="logout")
  private WebElement logoutbutton;

  if(logoutbutton.isEnabled())
  {
   logoutbutton.click();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare the element like this,

```
@AndroidFindBy(id = "com.care.android.careview:id/logout")
public MobileElement logoutButton;
```

Usage is :

```
logoutButton.click();
```

This should work.